# endOfConversation feature is not working in directline bot api of Dynamics

Tags: botframework, dynamics-crm, direct-line-botframework

I want to end conversation using direct line api (https://directline.botframework.com) but when I try sending message with type = "endOfConversation" according to official documentation to activities, it's not working.

I tried sending activity as normal to this endpoint just as directed in this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-end-conversation?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#send-an-endofconversation-activity

But It only sends this activity as normal activity, of course the type will be endOfConversation but it has no impact, and I wanted the conversation to be ended from customer side, so it shows agent that customer ended conversation and they can clear this conversation.

What should I do?